# New-UnifiedGroup doesn't work with ErrorAction

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0, azure-powershell

I am using the code below to create a public group using powershell in O365:

```
Try
{
     New-UnifiedGroup -AccessType Public -Alias $groupIdentity -DisplayName $groupDisplayName -Owner $smtpAddress
}
Catch
{
     # Some exception handling statements
}
```

But I don't see it reaching to catch in case of failure.
After investigation a little, I got to know that `-ErrorAction stop` needs to be used at the end of the command for it to reach to catch.
But When I do the below:

```
New-UnifiedGroup -AccessType Public -Alias $groupIdentity -DisplayName $groupDisplayName -Owner $smtpAddress -ErrorAction stop
```

this fails with the error below:

```
The "ErrorAction" parameter can't be used on the "New-UnifiedGroup" cmdlet because it isn't present in the role definition for the current user. Check the management roles assigned to you, and try again.
```

But again I have `Global Admin` role assigned to me so I have no idea what I am doing wrong.

Comment: We have this issue also, using global admin accounts.

Answer (score 0):

The error you have received is saying that you're not authorized to run that command with that specific parameter. You need to be assigned permissions before you can run this cmdlet.

Although this topic lists all parameters for the cmdlet, you may not have access to some parameters if they're not included in the permissions assigned to you. To find the permissions required to run any cmdlet or parameter in your organization, see [Find the permissions required to run any Exchange cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/exchange-server/find-exchange-cmdlet-permissions?view=exchange-ps).

To check if you're able to run any cmdlet with specific parameter you can use the following script:

```
# Define what you're looking for
$user   = 'joey@contoso.com'
$cmdlet = 'New-UnifiedGroup'
$param  = 'ErrorAction'

# Find all your assignments
$assignments = Get-ManagementRoleAssignment -RoleAssignee $user -Delegating $false

# Find cmdlets you can run and filter only the one you specified
$assignments.role | Foreach-Object {Get-ManagementRoleEntry "$_\*" | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq $cmdlet -and $_.Parameters -contains $param}}
```

In last line we're iterating all the roles assigned to you and checking role entries. Their format is `RoleName\CmdletName` so we're using * (wildcard) to get all. After last pipeline you're filtering only the results you want using `Where-Object` cmdlet.

Answer (score 0):

[Joey Cai](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8557999/joey-cai)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61474758/9902555) explains how to check if you're allowed to run the cmdlet with specific parameter.

I have checked it on my O365 tenant and apparently I'm not allowed to use `-ErrorAction` in `New-UnifiedGroup` so it seems to be default setting in Office 365. As a workaround, I'd use the following to temporarily change error action preference:

```bsh
$previousErrorAction = $ErrorActionPreference
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'
New-UnifiedGroup -AccessType Public -Alias $groupIdentity -DisplayName $groupDisplayName -Owner $smtpAddress
$ErrorActionPreference = $previousErrorAction
```

Comment: I'm experiencing the same. The problem I've found is that it seems setting a global ErrorActionPreference doesn't always trigger the catch block when Microsoft generate errors.

Comment: @Robin any example of such behavior?